# Get sub expression from boost::regex (before Match)

Tags: c++, regex, boost

How can get the sub expressions in boost::regex`(basic_regex<char, regex_traits<char> >)`object. (Without text to compare- befroe done `boost::regex_search`)

Examples:

> **Expression:** xx.*?yy
>
> **Expected Result:** 1 sub expression-

```
                 - xx.*?yy
```

> **Expression:** xx.*?yy | xx.*?zz
>
> **Expected Result:** 2 sub expression-

```
                - xx.*?yy

                - xx.*?zz
```

> **Expression:**  xx.*?yy|(xx.*?zz|aa.*?bb)
>
> **Expected Result:** 2 sub expression-

```
                -  xx.*?yy       

                - (xx.*?zz|aa.*?bb) -2 sub expression-
 
                       -  xx.*?zz

                       -  aa.*?bb
```

Answer (score 1):

`boost::regex` will allow you to extract *marked* (i.e. parenthesized) subexpressions:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  boost::regex r("xx.?yy|(xx.?zz|aa.*?bb)", boost::regex::save_subexpression_location);
  for (unsigned i = 1; i < r.mark_count(); ++i) {
    auto range = r.subexpression(i);
    std::cout << std::string(range.first, std::next(range.second)) << '\n';
  }
}
```

This will extract the marked subexpression `(xx.*?zz|aa.*?bb)`, but to get anything more precise you'll need a regex parser: [Lightweight regex parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306927/lightweight-regex-parser).

Comment: I meant to ask how can to get the expression divided by "or"

Comment: @user1790461 yes, you'll need a regex parser for that; it's not something that a regex implementation will offer.